# Set up new dedicated server

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, dedicated-server

I'm a newbie.
I just bought a new dedicated server which running windows server 2008 r2 and have an ip for example 128.98.34.112. I bought a domain xyz.com without hosting from godaddy.com and i want to host it to my new server. in godaddy.com i already follow this steps http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=237604. i also have installed plesk in my new server and create a domain with the name xyz.com and set the A record for xyz.com to 128.98.34.112, and set the NS record to ns1.xyz.com and ns2.xyz.com. But until now i still can not open the xyz.com from browser. Whats wrong? Do I need to install active directory to host a domain? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a lot of different problems here.  Here are some troubleshooting tests for windows.

Open a command prompt and type nslookup xyz.com 128.98.34.112.  If you get the right result that is good and DNS is working.  If not first try and telnet to port 53.  telnet 128.98.34.112 53.  If it does not connect with a blank screen then it is likely that your firewall is not open for port 53.  If it is able to connect, then it is likely a configuration issue on your dns server.  I have not used plesk so I cannot tell you how to check the DNS server settings.

If it returns the record then DNS is working, and it is likely that you may need to wait more time for it to hit the internet, or also try and clear your dns cache.  ipconfig /flushdns.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install and configure IIS? WIthout a web server - your web browser will not see anything.

Use "PING xxx" (xxx- the domain with www, on a command line) to see whether your DNS resolution works and the correct IP is resolved.

Comment: i have installed iis and bind xyz.com to ip 128.98.34.112. but when i ping 128.98.34.112 it can not find host xyz.com. and when i nslookup xyz.com it says DNS request timed out

Comment: You should not need bind, or? What did you set up as name servers at godaddy.com? If you can nto ping correctly and nslookup does not work, this is not at all a new server setup problem - it is a domain registration / setup issue.